# How to modify $uri to part of uri from request_uri in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Suppose the value of $request_uri is /a/b/c . The current value of $uri is /index.php . Is this possible to change my $uri to /b/c .

I have tried this, which doesn't seem to be working,

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  set $uri /$1/$2;
}
```

But this gives error of duplicate "uri" variable. I also tried,

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  rewrite ^ /$1/$2 break;
}
```

But $variables don't seem to store values.

Is there a way out? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just use a temporary variable? Eg (not tried):

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  set $tmp /$1/$2;
  rewrite ^ $tmp break;
}
```

---

or what about:

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  rewrite ^ $request_uri;
  rewrite ^/[^/]*/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
}
```

Comment: yup I tried that, and I don't get anything in $1 and $2. can you think of any other alternative, please?

Comment: what about 2 rewites, updated answer.

Comment: Can you explain that a little, the second rewrite?

Comment: I just replaced `a` by `[^/]*` because you did `~*`, so you wanted to match uppercase and lowercase which I dont think  you can do in rewrite. It just means any characters not including `/`.

Comment: I tried this one, it is also not working. And why did you not put flag for first rewrite?

Comment: If you mean the `break`, you cannot put it on the first rewrite as it will then stop doing any further commands.

Comment: Edited, Thanks man, it worked. I wasn't sure about flagless rewrite directive. Thank You Man. And sorry that I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputations. Though I have put the same question on stackoverflow, if you can post the answer over there, I can upvote there. Thanks a ton. Can you ping me at satya8081@gmail.com for any further discussions.

Comment: waht is i have ti do it in reverse.

$request_uri is "/a/b/c" but i need "/a/b/something _else"

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @MTeck in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084969/nginx-request-uri-without-args

If you really want exactly $request_uri with the args stripped, you can do this.

`local uri = string.gsub(ngx.var.request_uri, "?.*", "")`

You will need to have lua available but that will do exactly what you're asking.