# Nginx strip part of request uri

Tags: nginx

I have a scenario

```
location / {

# If the request_uri is /a/b/c 
# then proxy_pass http://upstream/c

}
```

Please help me out with any suggestions.
I saw this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/718610/how-to-modify-uri-to-part-of-uri-from-request-uri-in-nginx) , but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: rewrite solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Read the docs on proxy_pass.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028